# Load internal iframe from resource://

Tags: firefox, iframe, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a Firefox SDK Addon and at this phase I want to load an internal iframe from the Addon's resources but I get an error and the iframe content is blank.

How can I add an iframe and set the source with `resource://...`?

Comment: What's the error? What do you mean internal iframe? An iframe you created in `Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow`?

Comment: Without code, this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].